# Conditional Update Operation in Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'd like to increment a field if and only if the value of the field after the increment would be greater than or equal to 1. Otherwise, I'd like to set the value of the field to 1.

For example, say I have the following document:

```
{'id':1,'field':5}
```

I can accomplish my objective in two steps:

```
value = db.collection.find_and_modify({'id':1},{'$inc':{'field':-10}},new=True)

if value['field'] < 1:
    db.collection.find_and_modify({'id':1},{'$set':{'field':1}},new=True)
```

There must be a better way to accomplish this task; I'm not sure that I want to run two separate find_and_modify tasks if they can be consolidated into one.

Comment: Two steps are required. You can do it like you showed, or you can retrieve the document, modify the client-side copy, and update based on the client-side document.

Comment: Do you suspect that there would be any advantages to modifying the client-side copy over doing it the way I've described?

Comment: Are you accessing documents concurrently?